# How can I access Live Mesh from a Silverlight 3 app?

Tags: silverlight, live-mesh

I have an existing Silverlight 3 app that I want to add Live Mesh support to.  This may sound like a simple question but I can't figure out how to get started!  I've read a bit on dev.live.com but haven't found a good example.  Here's what I want to accomplish:

1. User visits my SL3 site.
2. User enters their Live ID and password to login to live (not sure how to do this either).
3. User sees a list of their files from Live Mesh.
4. User chooses a file, maybe a text file, and views it in my SL3 app.

Is this possible?  I've read about Silverlight enabled Mesh Apps, but it looks like those only run inside the "Live Desktop" part of Mesh.  This would be nice as a small addon to my current app but I don't want to push the entire app into the mesh to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible atm:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/liveframework/thread/bdeb4de4-3ccd-4510-a227-ae228bf6225f